# How to solve frequent DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN?

Tags: domain-name-system

A frequent problem always pops up in my workplace, sometimes computers fails to connect to the server or each other through their names, they only connects using the IP.

I am somewhat new to server environments. Having one with Windows 2008 R2 serving over 30 computers. Based on an advise from a friend, DHCP settings of the router, DNS servers are set to: 192.168.1.1 (Router's IP) as primary, and 192.168.1.2 (Server's IP) as secondary. Simultaneously, they fail to connect to certain websites including gmail, using google chrome it gives the error  DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN.

The only way I figured out to solve this is through restarting the local DNS Client services.

Using DNS setting obtained from our ISP did not solve the problem, only caused other problems, requiring users to re-enter their AD usernames and passwords to connect.

Is this a dns problem? Or a problem in some other settings that conflict with the dns clients? I have little information about DNS server, and when I checked it out on the web, I found it hard to understand the use of this technology in small business like ours. I hope that someone here could enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

`NXDOMAIN` for popular websites is unusual. This means that your DNS server successfully received a response from an upstream source stating that the record did not exist, and **not** due to a communication problem.

You need to examine your workplace infrastructure carefully and identify whether or not you have authoritative DNS servers (including DCs) that are configured to "steal" domains for popular websites. It's possible that there are leftovers of a misguided attempt to intercept specific DNS records to prevent employees from accessing them. Any network/security appliances which intercept DNS queries are also suspect.

As an example, what you're describing could occur if one of your servers is configured with a gmail.com domain, but not the others.

Comment: As I mentioned I am somewhat new to server environments and have little information about DNS servers, however, I ended up responsible for these issues. 

Can you refer to any guide that addresses this issue?

Please note that the websites access problem is accompanied with access problem to local server and computer through the network. 

I did not configure infrastructure nor local dns server in my workplace, but I am aware of the objective, and willing to restructure it if required!

Thank you very much for your concern.

Comment: Unfortunately it sounds like you're going to require an expert on the topics of AD and/or DNS. The best advice I can offer is to use packet captures to track every step of the DNS communication. Identify which DNS server you are seeing the NXDOMAIN coming from. If it's a device you own, run packet captures on that server and identify which DNS server it saw the NXDOMAIN come from. If you can confirm that the NXDOMAIN came from your ISP, take it up with them.

Comment: I should use the packet capture on the client when the problem occurs is that correct? Or should I use the packet capture on the server (192.168.1.2)? I again really thank you for your great concern.

Comment: Start from the client, identify the server/device which returned NXDOMAIN. Then run the packet capture on that device, and so on. You're tracking down where exactly it's coming from. Most packet capture software (Wireshark, etc.) will automatically dissect DNS packets for you. You're looking for the response code. (NOERROR, NXDOMAIN, SERVFAIL, etc.)